# realloc() issues: deallocation of old block,new size bigger than old size,and passing static array base address

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, memory-management

While reading about `realloc()` I have stumbled upon some doubts which I need to clarify rather than ignore.Your answers are very much sought.I have put them in a numbered list for clarity.Please don't mind the length of this question.

**1)** While using `realloc()`,if  the memory block with its contents are moved to a new location,does the orignal address gets **deallocated** as if we called free() on it?I've read the following from `cplusplusreference` about `realloc`,but though they come close to suggesting that the original memory block do get deallocated in such a case,yet I need your confirmation.

`->C90 (C++98)C99/C11 (C++11)
Otherwise, if size is zero, the memory previously allocated at ptr is deallocated as if a call to free was made, and a null pointer is returned.`

`->If the function fails to allocate the requested block of memory, a null pointer is returned, and the memory block pointed to by argument ptr is not deallocated (it is still 
valid, and with its contents unchanged).`

**2)**  Here's another line that raise questions: `"If the new size is larger, the value of the newly allocated portion is indeterminate."`.Well,here is what I want to know

**i)** Is it allowed to write into that newly allocated portion?

**ii)** Is the newly allocated portion filled using garbage values?

**3)** And finally,What if pass an **array object** to `realloc(`)?I ask because,though type will still be `char*`,it is mentioned in the source site that, the argument should be `"Pointer to a memory block previously allocated with malloc, calloc or realloc.`Will it be **UB** here too,as I read in `free()`'s description that for `free()` `"If ptr does not point to a block of memory allocated with the above functions, it causes undefined behavior."`

Comment: I have been advised not to use `cplusplusreference`.But the advice was recent while I've been taking notes from that site since a month.Hence it will take a while to transition!!And well,it's not **that** bad :-) !!

Answer (score 9):

> 1) While using `realloc()`,if the memory block with its contents are moved to a new location,does the orignal address gets deallocated as if we called `free()` on it?

Yes, if `realloc()` returns a pointer to a different location, the old location is `free`d.

It is not `free`d if `realloc` fails to obtain a large enough block of memory and returns `NULL`.

> 2) Here's another line that raise questions: "If the new size is larger, the value of the newly allocated portion is indeterminate.".Well,here is what I want to know
>
> i) Is it allowed to write into that newly allocated portion?

Yes, sure. That's the entire point of reallocating a larger block of memory.

> ii) Is the newly allocated portion filled using garbage values?

Filled with garbage, not filled at all - the contents of the memory block are indeterminate, except for the part that was copied from the old block. You should not care *what* bits there are, put your own stuff there before reading from it.

> 3) And finally,What if pass an array object to `realloc()`? I ask because,though type will still be `char*`,it is mentioned in the source site that, the argument should be "Pointer to a memory block previously allocated with `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`. Will it be UB here too,as I read in `free()`'s description that for `free()`

Yes, if you pass an argument (except `NULL`) to `realloc` that was not obtained from a previous call to `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` (without having been `free`d since), the behaviour is undefined.

The pointers that may legitimately be passed to `realloc` are exactly the same that may be passed to `free`.

Comment: +1 Thanks Sir.I doubt if I will be getting any answer more precise than this.You didn't miss anything that I asked.